# Facebook app 100% width

Tags: css, facebook

Is possible create facebook app with 100% width? Something like this:
https://apps.facebook.com/what_car_fits/
(app has 100% width with full page background image)

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: you have answered your question yourself. you have already seen that it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

In the app settings page (in the developer app), under the "Advanced" tab you have the "Canvas Settings".
In there select the "Fluid" option for the Canvas Width.